# How to fetch data by id from xml using php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm a PHP/developing novice and I haven't been able to find a tutorial with a solution to this particular problem.

I have a XML file from an API with product information for an online store. Each physical product has multiple "styles" that need to be listed on the same page. I want to do that using their id numbers.

```
<products>
  <product id="001">
    <name>Shirt 1 - Women's</name>
    <price>12.00</price>
    <color>blue</color>
  </product>

  <product id="002">
    <name>Shirt 1 - Men's</name>
    <price>12.00</price>
    <color>red</color>
  </product>
   ...
  <product id="023">
    <name>Shirt 12 - Women's</name>
    <price>15.00</price>
    <color>purple</color>
  </product>

  <product id="024">
    <name>Shirt 12 - Men's</name>
    <price>15.00</price>
    <color>yellow</color>
  </product>

</products>
```

Comment: This is a clear example **why you shouldn't** fetch data by id from xml. Please read: [Back to basics](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)

Comment: @YourCommonSense OP says that he get's the xml from an API. What would you suggest to do?

Comment: WE ALL get xml from an API. it doesn't mean we keep it as is. Say, I have a script that does parse around 500 XML files a day, and store contents in database. Do you have any other scenario?

Comment: @YourCommonSense If you do so you are talking about cached data. You won't be able to get live data this way. Btw, doing so is possible but very uncommon. There are better, transparent ways to cache data and take load from a server

Comment: take a look at `simplexml`, on http://www.php.net and on SO

Answer (score 1):

You could use a XSLT file to transform your XML to your HTML code. Here's some documentation, and examples, from php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php

Another solution would be to fetched the data from XML with the use of XPath queries. This way you can transform your XML data to a list of PHP objects which you can then use in your templating engine. Examples and info: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php